# How to conditionally add a className?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have the following with react-redux-form:

```
<fieldset>
  <label>{label}</label>
  <div>
    <input {...input} name="email" type="text" className="form-control" />
    {touched && error && <span className="error">{error}</span>}
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I would like to be able to update `<fieldset>` with either

```
className=""
className="has-success"
className="has-danger"
```

The logic would be:

- If `touched` but no `error`: `<fieldset className="has-success">`
- If `touched` and `error`: `<fieldset className="has-danger">`
- If not `touched` nor `error`: `<fieldset className="">`

How can I get this working in React?

Comment: Just updated the question to show that I needed your fault state which is the case one touch and error both not been set the true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it like so:

```
<fieldset className={touched ? (error ? "has-danger" : "has-success") : ""}> 
  ... 
</fieldset>
```

This first checks if `touched` is truthy. If it is, only then will it render a `<fieldset>` which class will be `"has-danger"` if `error` is truthy or `"has-success"` otherwise. If `touched`, *doesn't exist*, then the class is an empty string. This assumes that there will be no case where `touched` is falsey and `error` is truthy (though you could add more to handle that case).

If you find that this is a bit unreadable, maybe try using the [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) NPM package which is a bit more readable:

```
<fieldset className={classNames({
  "": !touched && !error,
  "has-danger": touched && error,
  "has-success": touched && !error
})}>
  ...
</fieldset>
```

This is more readable *and doesn't assume there won't be a case where `touched` is falsey and `error` is truthy*.

Comment: What about the default case when it's not touched or error?

Comment: @AnApprentice Then it won't render anything. You didn't mention anything about it.

Comment: perfect. Thank you