# How do I set className based on three conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have the functional component:

```
let renderEmailField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, pristine}}) =>
    <fieldset className=????
     .....
```

I currently am using this ternary expression to conditionally add a class:

```
<fieldset className={touched ? (error ? "has-danger" : "has-success") : ""}>
```

The problem with the above is it does not take into account the new `pristine` prop, where if `pristine` is true, then `"has-success"` should not be added since the user hasn't done anything.

How can I update the above `className` logic, to only add `"has-danger"` or `"has-success"` if `pristine` is false?

Comment: Why didn't you ask this in your original question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44856989/5647260

Comment: this is a new problem for this am, didn't have it yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that using ternary operators isn't the best. You could set it with some `if` statements, but I find a much cleaner way with the [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package, which can also be inline. Currently, the code you have now would look like this with `classnames`:

```
<fieldset className={classNames({
  "": !touched && !error,
  "has-danger": touched && error,
  "has-success": touched && !error
})}>
  ...
</fieldset>
```

You could change the conditions for `"has-danger"` and `"has-success"` to account for `pristine` like so:

```
<fieldset className={classNames({
  "": !touched && !error,
  "has-danger": !pristine && touched && error, //you could cache !prinstine && touched as to not have duplicate code
  "has-success": !pristine && touched && !error
})}>
  ...
</fieldset>
```

For each potential class to add, you describe a certain condition for it to be added. If `touched` is truthy and `error` is falsey, then add no class. If not `pristine`, and `touched`, and `error`, then `"has-danger"` is added. If not `pristine`, and `touched`, and no `error`, then add `"has-success"`. You could even get rid of the first condition because it's a tad useless and add your own cases.

Comment: very nice - trying this package now

Comment: @AnApprentice Yeah, I mentioned in my answer yesterday too.

Answer (score 2):

I think, writing multiple conditions using `ternary operator` is not a good idea, what you can do here is simply call a function and put `if-else` conditions inside that and `return` the class name from that function.

Like this:

```
<fieldset className={this._setClassName()}/>

_setClassName(){
    if()
       return "a";
    else if()
       return "b";
    else
       return "c";
}
```

For `Functional components`, use `{}`, put all the logic for class name and use that with `fieldset` element.

Like this:

```
let renderEmailField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, pristine}}) => {
     let className = "";
     if()
        className = "a";
     else if()
        className = "b";
     else
        className = "c";

     return(
         <fieldset className={className}/>
     )
}
```

Comment: that's a good call but right now this lives inside `let renderEmailField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, pristine}}) =>
  <fieldset className={touched ? (error ? "has-danger" : "has-success") : ""}>` where I can't run a function right?